# How can I restrict read access to firebase data using security rules?

Tags: security, firebase

I'm learning firebase using the example firetube. The "write" rules work fine but  I would like to allow a user to access his own data only.

I tried to compare the logged-in id of the user with the userid value stored in the userid field of each record using the read rules as follow but it fails

```
{
  "rules": {
    "comments": {
      "$commentID": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.provider === 'password' && auth.id ==      data.child('userid').val()",        
        ".write": // write rule here...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the write rule should look about the same as the read rule. What sort of problems are you running into?

Comment: I tried a lot of combination but always get the same error

User Id: 16, Email: jlcurty@gmail.com firetube.js:13
FIREBASE WARNING: on() or once() for /comments failed: Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.  firebase.js:34
here is the example :
http://jlcurty.github.io/firetube1/

Comment: Have you tried using the Security Simulator? It's in the sidebar in Forge. You can test reads / writes there.

Comment: I did but could'nt figure out what is wrong ...